# FrameTicks not appearing with Export to .png file

Tags: bugs, export, ticks

I'm using 10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to export some plots.  However, when I export the plots using `Export[file.png, figure, ImageResolution->360]`, the `FrameTicks` fail to appear.  If I export to a PDF file, the `FrameTicks` appear. Here's an example.

```
list = {{{10., 5.}, {40., 20.}, {160., 80.}}, {{10., 1.83772}, {40.,13.6754}, {160., 67.3509}}, {{10., 8.16228}, {40., 26.3246}, {160.,92.6491}}};

 myPlot = ListPlot[list, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Sample Size n", "Number of Successes: k "},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Large, FontSize -> fontsize],
 ImageSize -> 6*72]

Export["plot.pdf", myPlot, ImageResolution -> 360]
Export["plot.png", myPlot, ImageResolution -> 360]
```

Here's the pdf file

[image: plot.pdf]

Here's the png file

[image: plot.png]

```
Options[myPlot]
```

Returns

```
{DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], 
    Scaled[0.05]}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 160.}, {0, 92.6491}}, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> {False, False}, 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[Large], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontWeight -> "Bold", 
   FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontSize -> 14}, 
 DisplayFunction :> Identity, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {{"Number of Successes: k ", None}, {"Sample Size n", 
    None}}, FrameStyle -> Thickness[Large], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Large, FontSize -> 12], 
 GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], ImageSize -> 432, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontWeight -> "Bold", 
   FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontSize -> 12}, Method -> {}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 160.}, {0, 92.6491}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], 
    Scaled[0.05]}}, PlotRegion -> {{0, 0.975}, {0.025, 1}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, TicksStyle -> Thickness[Large]}
```

Anyone have a work around besides converting the PDFs to PNGs outside of *Mathematica*?